# javascript opening a new window, setting its content AND its location without reloading that location for security

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, location, innerhtml

I am trying to implement an HTTP(due to memory resource limitation on embedded devices I can't use HTTPS) webserver security system.

I need to do this in case a hacker deploy a webserver with the same IP as mine (yes I know about IP conflict it shouldn't be possible but I tried and it worked) or hack my DNS server which will result in his server and mine to have the same domain for the browser and as result, the hacker can access the session storage in which I'm storing credentials (i know I shouldn't use session storage for credentials but due to many other vulnerabilities this is the best I can work with).

For this reason, before opening every page I must check that the received page is actually the original webpage and not a page sent by a hacker (phishing page for example) to extract the credentials, if it is a valid page I can continue and open it in the browser, and if not valid an alert is shown.

I check the validity of the page by checking a turning key only known by a (locally saved HTML file or a browser's extension) and the server with an ajax function. The key is sent with the page in the header:

```
var url="http://192.168.8.14";
......
xhr.onreadystatechange  = function() 
{ 
    if(xhr.readyState  == 4 && xhr.status  == 200)
    {
            if (xhr.getResponseHeader("identity_key") == identity_key) 
            {
               //ORIGINAL WEB PAGE
            }  
    }
}; 
xhr.open("GET", url+"?userIndex="+userIndex+"&identificationSalt="+identificationSalt,  true); 
xhr.send(null);
```

now i have all the validated html page inside the xhr.responseText which i would like to open inside a new tab or current tab and with the location pointing to url because the validated page contain relative paths and javascript src files  with relatives paths which need the location to work like this :

`<script src="sha.js"></script>` or  `window.location.href = "http://"+window.location.host+"/controle`

but when the location is pointing to the URL it mustn't reload the page otherwise the browser will load another page that is not validated.

I tried every way I can think of including this :

```
var url="http://192.168.8.14";
......
xhr.onreadystatechange  = function() 
{ 
    if(xhr.readyState  == 4 && xhr.status  == 200)
    {
            if (xhr.getResponseHeader("identity_key") == identity_key) 
            {
                    history.pushState(null, null, url);
                    document.documentElement.innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
            }  
    }
}; 
xhr.open("GET", url+"?userIndex="+userIndex+"&identificationSalt="+identificationSalt,  true); 
xhr.send(null);
```

but it gave me this error:

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://192.168.8.14/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'file:///C:/Users/ladne/Desktop/Untitled-1.html'.
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (file:///C:/Users/ladne/Desktop/Untitled-1.html:73:33)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBe30.jpg)

i also tried :

```
var page = window.open();
page.document.open(); 
page.document.location="http://192.168.8.14/";  
page.document.write(xhr.responseText);
page.document.close();
```

can anyone help, please?